# Where are the electric pieces for 42029?

Tags: piece-information

I was building LEGO 42029 Customized Pickup Truck, when I got to a page where I needed electrical parts, such as the battery box and the wires. I checked and these pieces were NOT included. Should they have been included? If not, where can I buy them?

Answer (score 8):

These pieces are not included in the set. Motorizing this set requires the addition of a Power Functions motor as shown here:

[image: instructions image showing combined sets]

You'll need the Power Functions Motor Set (8293) if you'd like to motorize your truck. This can be ordered from [shop.lego.com](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/LEGO-Power-Functions-Motor-Set-8293) or other online retailers. It's usually hard to find in stores, but if you have a LEGO store nearby, they will likely carry it.